# ¿Cómo pasar una columna de SQL Datetime a java?

Tags: java, sql, datetime, jdbc, timestamp

Hace tiempo tengo problemas a la hora de manejar las fechas en sql a la hora de pasarlas a Java. Una tabla en mi base de datos es de tipo Datetime y no estoy seguro de cómo pasarla a Java.
He probado cambiar Datetime a Timestamp, pero a la hora de hacer la conversión se muestra mal. Por ejemplo, el timestamp "16-06-2021 13:00:00" al pasarlo a Java se muestra como "16-06-2021 07:00:00". No sé a qué se debe esto.
Este es mi código para transformar los valores de una fila al objeto correspondiente:

```
public Showtime_Info from (ResultSet rs){
        try {
            Showtime_Info info= new Showtime_Info();
            info.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            info.setSchedule(rs.getTimestamp("date").toLocalDateTime());
            info.setNumAud(rs.getInt("auditorium_num"));
            info.setNumMovie(rs.getInt("movies_num"));
            return info;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            return null;
        }
```

Atributos de el objeto Showtime_Info:

```
private int id;
private LocalDateTime schedule;
private int numMovie;
private int numAud;
```

Tabla de mySQL

| id(int) | date(timestamp) | auditorium_num | movie_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-16 13:00:00 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: ¿Cuál motor de base de datos?

Comment: @Sal MySQL Workbench

Comment: ¿Sabes la zona horaria configurada en MySQL? Puedes intentar con: `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;`

Comment: @Sal SYSTEM y SYSTEM

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar mas formato de fechas en la documentación https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
              SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //Aca poner el formato de la fecha en tu DB
              Date fecha = null;
                try {
                    fecha = formato.parse(rs.getTimestamp("date"));
                } 
                catch (ParseException ex) 
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
                          
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");  // Aqui usamos la instancia formatter para darle el formato a la fecha. Es importante ver que el resultado es un string.
                String fechaTexto = formatter.format(fecha);
                                    
                
                System.out.println("FECHA: " + fechaTexto);
```